# downgrade laravel-sitemap in laravel 5.6.4

Tags: laravel-5

I have project Laravel with 5.6.4
I can't upgrade php because it isn't suitable for Laravel 5.6.4
so I installed PHP 5.6.4
but I have a problem in spatie/laravel-sitemap not suitable for PHP 5.6.4
(Problem 1
- spatie/laravel-sitemap[2.2.0, ..., 2.4.0] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-sitemap ^2.2 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-sitemap[2.2.0, ..., 2.4.0)

and I tried many versions and made problems also
I want suitable version of spatie/laravel-sitemap with php 5.6.4